# Intercept ASP.NET MVC 4 response generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

What I need to do is execute some code before the MVC executes the controller and after it finishes generating the View.
Is there any way to do this?

I need to integrate the MVC application with an existing cache system, so:

- before executing the controller, instantiate a cache.
- after the view was generated, destroy the cache.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at the [`ActionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) attribute.

Comment: [ActionFilter or HttpModule](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/15/http-modules-versus-asp-net-mvc-action-filters.aspx) discussion should be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action Filter Attributes enable you to inject code interceptors into the request of a MVC controller that can execute before and after a Controller or its Action methods execute.

For more detail, see: [Understanding Filter Interceptors by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx)

Comment: I had to use OnActionExecuting and OnResultExecuted to handle the events I want. thx

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` in global.asax or am I missing something?

Comment: I remember trying those, but they didn't get fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hook into page events, you'll probably want to implement your own [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) classes. Specifically, you'll want to decorate the Execute method. Phil Haack [has a blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx) on how to do this.